# Is there a way to connect Firebase Realtime Database to Compose Multiplatform project?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, firebase-realtime-database, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

I started working on a desktop application in Intelij Idea with Compose Multiplatform plugin. I want to connect Firebase Realtime Database to this project. But I couldn't find anything on this topic, is it possible? if so how to do it?

I tried to use Firebase Kotlin SDK, but apparently it doesn't support desktop applications.  The last hope is the Firebase REST API, but before I deal with it, I would like to understand if it can solve my problem, and are there any easier solutions for it.

Comment: Please describe the exact error you received

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request to support Firebase Database. Vote for the feature using the thumbs-up button on the right of the issue summary [DBE-12900](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-12900). As a workaround check [How to connect/use Firebase in Intellij Idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67646165/how-to-connect-use-firebase-in-intellij-idea))